# Cannot create asp.net mvc view using visual studio 2010, please help

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I am mvc 2 newbie.  got this weird error message, couldn't figure out how to fix it.

I am using visual studio 2010 and my project is asp.net mvc 2 using .net 4.0

I right clicked inside the action method to generate the view. It kept giving me error message.  I dont have that problem before,  only happened in this project.

[image]

Comment: the text in that image is very small... can you please write out the name of the assembly that is missing

Comment: if are an MVC 2 newbie you should switch to MVC 3

Comment: right click on the image, you will see the full size. but I already figure out what the problem is.  It is security issue.

Answer (score 0):

If it happens on everything, try reinstalling Visual Studio.
If it's a problem only with MVC Framework, try dwonloading it from here http://www.asp.net/mvc and install again. FileNotFoundException in the VS directory indicates that probably some required files are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I assume Tut.Domain is something you have built? If so, you either are not building it, or it is not located in the correct location for the application to pick up. If you read the end of the error message, prior to stack trace, it mentions Tut.Domain, which is where your troubleshooting should begin.

Comment: it is security issue. Moved the entire solution to another drive. problem solved.  Weird , but I just happy that I can continue working on it.